# Eclipse RCP proposal define color

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to set my custom color for the Proposal, but does not working for me

```java
StyledString displayString = new StyledString(displayString);
Styler styler = StyledString.createColorRegistryStyler(JFacePreferences.HYPERLINK_COLOR, JFacePreferences.HYPERLINK_COLOR);
displayString.setStyle(0, 1, styler );
return new JavaCompletionProposal(string, offset - length, length, null, displayString, 1);
```

Comment: `displayString.setStyle(0, 1, styler )` sets the style for a single character at the start of the string - is that what you actually want?

Comment: yes, only first character

Comment: What did I miss?

Comment: Has that colour been defined in the JFace registry - what does `JFaceResources.getColorRegistry().get(JFacePreferences.HYPERLINK_COLOR)` return?

Comment: return value ist Color {0, 102, 204, 255}

Comment: Anything wring?

Comment: What I observed, earlier in my code completion the typed words are displayed bold. This do not work anymore.
What I am doing other, is that I defined my custom editor and do not using the GenericEditor anymore.
Maybe something like on this direction?